# Migrate a Pygtk application with GLADE files, working under Debian, into MS Windows10. HOWTO?

Tags: qt, pygtk, glade, pygobject, pyusb

I would like to migrate a PyGtk (&PyUSB) application using GLADE and CSS files from a Debian9 (linux) PC into a Windows10 PC. What would be the recommendation?
a) rewrite in PyQt?
b) rewrite in C++ & Qt?
c) .. just implement a Python and Gtk environment in Windows10? 
Perhaps there is not a general answer and I should try c) before I rewrite the whole application? Any recommendation is welcome (I dont know Qt and C++.. so, it could be time consuming to do a) or b) for me). Any new recommendation is welcome.

The PyGtk application starts with

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk, Gdk as gdk, GLib, GObject as gobject
gobject.threads_init()
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
import threading
```

Answer (score 0):

First, this is not PyGTK (GTK2 bindings for python). This is PyGObject (which includes GTK3 bindings).

Option c) is possible with:

1. Just a normal install of [Python for Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) and an [`.exe` installer of the PyGObject](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/) library. But it only supports up to Python 3.4 (32 and 64 bits).
2. A MSYS2 install as described in the [PyGObject docs](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#windows-logo-windows) which supports up to Python 3.7 I believe.

Rewrite in PyQt5/PySide2 seems like a good plan B if for some reason the porting is too troublesome. I don't have much experience with it, but I read good things and initial tests seem to work fine.

Comment: not on time, but with python 2.7 everything should work easier(I use3.4 for compatibiliy reason on win32). Plus, pyusb works well, I have an app for industrial scale (from get value to pdf raport and papers) in 2.7 that still work